# Is there any issue if I make my prior job title more generic on my resume? For ex: "Sr Marketing Associate" versus "Sr Digital Marketing Associate"

Tags: resume, recruitment, hiring, title, employment

I am working on updating my resume, and I was thinking about changing how I present my prior job title(s). I want to make clear, I am NOT suggesting overstating my title (saying I was a Manager when I was an Associate).

In this example, I want to use "Senior Marketing Associate" instead of "Senior Digital Marketing Associate".

Would this be a problem or issue for you as a hiring manager?

Comment: Why would removing details be clearer?

Comment: 'Digital' seems redundant these days. What other Marketing is there? Manual?

Comment: Because job titles can vary so much between companies, most hiring managers care much more about what you do rather than what you are called.

Comment: @LaconicDroid but machines care, and they filter the results before people see them. So it's like Pin the Tail on the Donkey, but with personal wealth consequences.

Answer (score 6):

> Would this be a problem or issue for you as a hiring manager?

If I were the hiring manager, and during a reference check I found that the company had a different title than you indicated, it would definitely be an issue.

If I thought it was an honest mistake, I might ask you about it. And I would want to hear a convincing reason for the discrepancy.

If I conclude that you were being intentionally deceptive, you wouldn't be invited back.

Comment: That really depends on the title and responsibilities. The biggest discrepancy I had was when I was a "Junior Accounting Assistant". I had root access to their accounting database and was performing DB index optimization, creating multi-join reports across multiple dozens of tables, and also automating their internal processes. I also had 10 years of experience as a software developer at that time, so it was a bit weird.

Comment: @Nelson just imagine what the Senior could do!

Answer (score 6):

You would indeed be overstating your title.  I don't know a hill of beans about marketing, but I can infer from it that your current duties specifically don't include radio, TV, or print.  Depending on how much someone else actually reads your resume (it will vary) they might be turned off to learn later at the interview stage that your experience doesn't include these other areas.

Titles do matter.  If you didn't want to get stuck in a narrow title, you might have requested the title change when you started the job.

Comment: Does anyone watch TV, listen to radio or... read print these days?

Comment: @HappyIdiot yes (literally listening now)

Comment: @mattfreake it's always someone.

Answer (score 1):

Potential employers are going to look much more carefully at your description of what you did than at the title you were given. If you didn't work with traditional media or bulk-mail campaigns, and they want someone with that experience, the fact that you only cite online activity would be concerning. But that would be an issue no matter which title you had been working under.

For one theater production, I had the titles (in the program) of Senior Electrician and Lighting Crew Chief. In fact I was the only electrician and the entire lighting crew other than the lighting designer. Title helps catch the eye... but doesn't win the credit. Especially now that companies are using machine scoring to do the initial filtering of applicants; keywords in descriptions may matter more than they used to.

Comment: "*Titles aren't everything, they're the* only *thing.*"

Comment: @HappyIdiot: Inside a company, maybe, if they are tied to pay grade and/or authority. Across companies, not so much since they're not standardized. "Digital marketing associate" in one company may be an actual campaign designer while in the company across the street it may be a synonym for website monkey.

Comment: Maybe we should standardize them if they are being machine-scored? We could use that Metric System thing too...